# can I save a file to the current directory in air?

Tags: file, air, local

I have inherited an air app, and I don't know a lot of the capabilities and limitations of air.  Can I open a local from the current directory for read and write?

Using FileReference, I have been able to save a file to my /Documents directory.  But is there way to have it just save in the current directory?  Or have the prompt that currently comes up default to the current directory instead of my /Documents dir?

I've read http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Filesystem_08.html, and can't figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If current directory happens to be application directory, then no. AIR has concept of various directories:

- File.applicationDirectory - where app itself is installed, read-only.
- File.applicationStorageDirectory - buried somewhere deep (on Windows, it is C:\Documents and Settings[User name]\Application Data[Application name]\Local Store) - *you can use it to store files*.
- File.documentsDirectory - shortcut to current user's documents directory. Do not throw garbage there.
- File.desktopDirectory - shortcut to user's desktop, should be treated even more carefully.

Comment: There is also a, File.userDirectory - shortcut to user's directory.